Equations Automatically Set to Bold When Reopening Doc
I have a doc with lots of equations. I am using Insert | Equation to insert blank custom equations (table line) where I then write out my equations.
The problem: Word is converting my equations to bold when I save the doc and reopen it.
I managed to reproduce the problem in a small test doc:

Now I add a sentence at the bottom, save and reopen the doc. The equations are now bold.

Ideally, I would upload my little test file, but I don't see how to do that here.
Any ideas how to fix this?
Thanks
Edit: All the faulty equations were formatted as a line of a table. I couldn't solve this problem (maybe there is some background style in Word that overrides the non-bold formatting?). My workaround: Recreate the problematic equations WITHOUT tables (shortcut alt-= in Word for Windows).
